# Intersection of two lists in kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

How can we intersect two lists in kotlin and save it in another variable(collection of String)

for example I have two lists like this

```
val list: MutableList<JSONArray> = Arrays.asList(requestedFields)
val otherList: MutableList<MutableList<String>> = Arrays.asList(requiredFields)
```

Any help is highly appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the intersect method: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/intersect.html

For example:

```
val first = listOf("Ragh", "Cat")
val second = listOf("Dog", "Ragh", "Giraffe")
    
val third = first.intersect(second)
    
println(third) // prints [Ragh]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick help robin. so how can we  merge the two lists if we have first = ["ragh", "cat"] and second  is {0= "dog", 1= "ragh", 2 = "giraffe"}

Comment: @Raghu maybe you want `union` instead? *Intersect* means the items that are in *both* collections (where they overlap basically) - so in this case that's just a set containing only one item, `"Ragh"`. *Union* means the items that are in one collection or the other, everything combined, so `first.union(second)` gives you a set containing `["Ragh", "Cat", "Dog", "Giraffe"`]. You get a `Set` from these operations, so that's unique elements only - no duplicates. You can call `toList()` on it if you want a list at the end